# Excluding undesired .dll import from PyQt5 while creating an executable with cx_freeze under Python 3.6

Tags: pyqt5, cx-freeze, python-3.6

I do have one question regarding PyQt5 and cx_freeze, and I hope you can help me.
I would like to know if there is a way to exclude undesired .dll import from PyQt5 library while creating an executable with cx_freeze. This request comes from the fact that when I create my executable with cx_freeze the whole PyQt5 library is imported resulting in a quite heavy application (~220 Mb).

In my cx_freeze setup.py I have coded the following:

```
import sys
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.

base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

build_options={ "packages": ["os", "numpy.core._methods", 
"numpy.lib.format", "pywinusb", "numpy"],
            "includes":["PyQt5.QtQml", "PyQt5.QtWidgets"],
            "excludes":["tkinter",
                        "PyQt5.QtBluetooth",
                        "PyQt5.QtNetwork",
                        "PyQt5.QtNfc",
                        "PyQt5.QtWebChannel",
                        "PyQt5.QtWebEngine",
                        "PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore",
                        "PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets",
                        "PyQt5.QtWebKit",
                        "PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets",
                        "PyQt5.QtWebSockets",
                        "PyQt5.QtSql",
                        "PyQt5.QtNetwork",
                        "PyQt5.QtScript",
                        "numpy.core._dotblas"],
            "optimize": 2}

executables = [
    Executable('my_python_app.py', base=base)
] 

setup(
    name='my_python_app',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'my_python_app',
    options = {"build_exe": build_options},
    executables = executables,
    platforms='windows',
    include_package_data = True,
    install_requires=None,
    namespace_packages=None,
    keywords = []
)
```

Excluding the single modules (such as "PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore"), does not automatically exclude the associated .dll library (circa 40 Mb). After the build is created the .dll library in C:..\build\exe.win32-3.6\PyQt5\Qt\bin\Qt5WebEngineCore.dll is present.

As some of these libraries aren't needed, is there a way to tell cx_freeze to exclude them?

For reference, I'm using:

- Windows 7 Enterprise, Service Pack 1
- Python 3.6 32-bit
- cx_Freeze-5.0.2

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: We've got the same issue.   so far, we have a post install script that simply deletes them all before archiving

Comment: Hi Erik, thank you for your feedback, would be possible for you to share some more information on how your script works? Thank you